# weighted moving average with Hive SQL

Tags: sql, hive, moving-average, weighted-average

Given a Hive table like below I want to calculate a weighted moving average. In table 1 is an example of such a weighted moving average. The value of every column is

```
col_value = (1 * n) + (0.75 * n-1) + (0.5 * n-2) + (0.25 * n-3) 
where n is the value at the current row, n-1 the value at the above row, etc.
```

More info on weighted moving averages on the [corresponding Wikipedia section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Weighted_moving_average)

Im stuck after calculating the moving average like so:

**Code sample 1: Query so far**

```
SELECT
    *,
    AVG (value) OVER (
        ORDER BY
            id
        ROWS BETWEEN
            3 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
FROM
    table
```

**Table 1:**

```
id    value    weighted_moving_average   code_sample_1
...
11     0        0                        0
12     1        1                        0.25
13     0        0.75                     0.25
14     0        0.5                      0.25
15     0        0.25                     0.25
16     0        0                        0
...
```

Comment: can you explain the logic for `wanted` column?

Comment: what do you get from running that query?

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, see updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the window size to be easily changed, then the implementation would be substantially different.

(Please note that I developed this in [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server) because I am not aware of any website I can test [hive](/questions/tagged/hive) SQL. You may need to tweak some syntax.)

```
Declare @thisManyRows int = 3;
With rowNumber_cte As (
    Select 
        id, 
        [Value],
        RowNo = Row_Number() Over (Order By id)
      From Table1),
windows_cte As (
    Select
        b_id = b.id,
        j_id = j.id,
        j.[Value],
        RowNo2 = @thisManyRows + 1 - Row_Number() Over (Partition By b.id Order By j.id desc),
        n = Count(j.[Value]) Over (Partition By b.id)
      From rowNumber_cte As b
      Join rowNumber_cte As j On j.RowNo Between b.RowNo - @thisManyRows + 1 And b.RowNo)
Select
    id = b_id,
    [Value] = Sum(Case When b_id = j_id Then [Value] Else Null End),
    WeightedAverage = Sum([Value] * 1.0 * (RowNo2 *1.0 / @thisManyRows)) / Min(n)
  From windows_cte
  Group By b_id;
```

I'm going to explain what this does because it's a bit cryptic:

1. Set the variable to the number of rows to consider for the moving average (including the current row).
2. In the `rowNumber_cte` we assign a row number, we do this because we don't assume that `id` will be sequential.
3. In the `windows_cte` we join the `rowNumber_cte` on itself, so that each row is joined to all the rows that make up it's window of calculation (with reference to the `@thisManyRows` variable. This cte also introduces a new `RowNo2` field which will basically end up being the numerator of the fraction for which this row's value contributes to the weighted moving average (i.e. the current row, if the window is 4 will have `RowNo2 = 4` and will have 4/4 weight).
4. `windows_cte` also calculates the number of rows in the window to better handle rows at the start of the data which don't have a full window.
5. The final select groups by `id`, multiplies the `[Value]` of each row in the window by it's weight and then divides by the number of rows in the window: `n`.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't fancy, but it is a start.

```
SELECT
    *,
    (SUM (value*0.25) OVER (ORDER BY id ROWS BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) +
     SUM (value*0.25) OVER (ORDER BY id ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) +
     SUM (value*0.25) OVER (ORDER BY id ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) +
     value * 0.25) /
    COUNT (value) OVER (ORDER BY id ROWS BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
FROM
    table;
```

Comment: Any way to make the window size dynamic?

Comment: Not in his method. I can think of a different way to do it that could be dynamic but I haven't time to write it now.